# SQL .How to find records with almost identical string values?

Tags: sql, database, string, sqlite, subquery

Let's say I have this table (**products**):

```
part_number   product_name
1202          airpods
1204          ipod
1398          iphone 6
1304          watch I
1378          iphone 7
1244          airpods 2
```

And I want to select the all the records where the `part_number` has at least one (almost perfect) match with the exception of the third character. So the end result would look something like this:

```
part_number   product_name
1204          ipod
1398          iphone 6
1378          iphone 7
1244          airpods 2
```

It's there a way to use the LIKE operator to do this? I know LIKE can find patterns when stating several known characters but in this case I don't necessarily know what those are.

Note:Yeah, the part_number field is defined as string, not numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want rows for which another row exists with a partial match on the part number: the first two digits and the last one should match, while the third differs.

You can use `exists`. Assuming that `part_number` is an integer (as it *should be*), you can do this with arithmetics:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (
    select 1
    from products p1
    where 
        p1.part_number <> p.part_number
        and p1.part_number / 100 = p.part_number / 100
        and p1.part_number - p1.part_number / 10 * 10 = p.part_number - p.part_number / 10 * 10
)
```

You can also use string functions - which make the query somehow more understandable (although maybe less efficient):

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (
    select 1
    from products p1
    where 
        p1.part_number <> p.part_number
        and substr(p1.part_number, 1, 2) = substr(p.part_number, 1, 2)
        and substr(p1.part_number, 4, 1) = substr(p.part_number, 4, 1)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=81351e96003b739082eb01c40b3af5da)** - Both querires yield:

```
part_number | product_name
:---------- | :-----------
1204        | ipod        
1398        | iphone 6    
1378        | iphone 7    
1244        | airpods 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I was looking for. In my case, the string solution is perfect just because there are some records of part_numbers that contain letters i.e. 12#7.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got SQLite on hand but in most SQL variations this works:

```
select * from test t1 where exists
(
 select * from test t2 where t2.part_number != t1.part_number 
 and left(t1.part_number,2) = left(t2.part_number,2)
 and right(t1.part_number,1) = right(t2.part_number,1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this one in SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT()` window function:

```
select part_number, product_name
from (
  select *, 
    count(*) over (partition by substr(part_number, 1, 2), substr(part_number, -1)) counter
  from products
)
where counter > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2pgvzWCMtb1oK3iTtjhc54/0).
Results:

```
| part_number | product_name |
| ----------- | ------------ |
| 1204        | ipod         |
| 1244        | airpods 2    |
| 1398        | iphone 6     |
| 1378        | iphone 7     |
```

Comment: Interesting! I hadn't thought about using COUNT() for that

Comment: @Mafe this is the most performant way to do it. I'm surprised that you chose such a complex way.